# Redux Toolkit Reducers and ExtraReducers : Calling a reducer that has a prepare callback from within an extra reducer doesn't call reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I am building a notification system using Redux Toolkit and I am running into an issue.
Here I want to trigger the showNotification when certain actions/reducers in other slices are called.  So I have added extraReducer to my NotificationSlice. When I call dispatch(showNotification(type, message, duration)) from a component it goes through prepare callback and then the reducer as expected.  However, when I call showNotification from the extraReducer case for handleLogInFailure() I see that it hits the prepare callback, but it never hits the reducer.

I tried changing the showNotification implementation in the extra reducer to use caseReducers:

However, this seems to bypass the prepare callback, which would then force me to call it with a full action (below) which is more verbose than I want if I have to have over 100 different extraReducers:

```
const { showNotification } = notificationSlice.caseReducers;
showNotification(state, {type: 'notification/handleLoginFailure', payload: { type, message, durations }});
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Current Implementation:

```
const notificationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notification',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    showNotification: {
      reducer(
        state: NotificationState,
        action: PayloadAction<{ type: NotificationType; message: string; duration?: number }>
      ) {
        console.log('showNotification: REDUCE', action)
        const { type, message, duration } = action.payload;


        state.notifications.push(buildNotification(type, message, duration));
      },
      prepare(type: NotificationType, message: string, duration?: number) {

        console.log('showNotification: PREPARE', {type, message, duration})
        return {
          payload: {
            type,
            message,
            duration,
          },
        };
      },    },
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(handleLogInFailure, (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      const error = action.payload;
      
      console.log('Notifications: handleLogInFailure', action)
      showNotification('error', error)
    });
  },
```

I was expecting that calling the reducer from the extraReducer (w/o using the caseReducers pattern) would properly go through the prepare callback and then go to the reducer.

Comment: You are calling an action creator function from within a reducer.  This fundamentally doesn't make sense and it will not have any impact on your state.  Probably you need a middleware to `dispatch` your `showNotification` action when you encounter a `handleLoginFailure` action.